# Download KML File Instead of View in Browser

Tags: php, download, kml

I am working on a project which creates a KML File (just like an XML file, but used for Google Earth). Whats interesting is when I link to the newly created file, on my local machine, running XAMPP, the file is downloaded automatically, however when I move it to my web server (Linux, Fedora 8 on EC2) the link just loads the KML file in the browser as if it was an HTML file.

How can I force it to download the file instead of viewing it in the browser?

Here's how to link is displayed with PHP,

```
echo "<a href='$currentTime.kml'><img heigth=\"15px\" width=\"13px\" src=\"images/KML_Icon.gif\" /> Download</a>";
```

Any advice would help, thanks!

Comment: Is the correct mime type for KML files setup on the server? If not, an incorrect mime type will be sent to the browser and you may not see the expected behavior.

Comment: @Oded application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml is not present in my mimes.type file on the server, but it is on my local box, so I think this is the problem

Comment: Sounds likely - add it to your apache configuration and see what happens.

Comment: I added it, and nothing is happening, perhaps I need to restart apache

Comment: This worked, if you answer I'll mark as correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for your guys' input, but Oded had the answer regarding the mime types.

On the server there's a file called mime.types which didn't contain the mime type for a KML file, I added in

```
application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml
```

And it now downloads the file instead of loading it in the browser, by the way apache needs to be restarted once you have made the changes.

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do is to specify the headers so the Browser knows what to do with the information that you are sending. So before you send anything to the browser you will need to specify the headers.

If you are linking to a specific file, then you will have to create a little "download manager" that will do this for you.

```
<?
  header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=the-name-you-want-them-to-see-in-their-download.pdf');
  header('Content-type: text/xml'); //Since KML files are based on XML this is probably the best Content type to send to the user.
  readfile('the-file-you-want-to-present')
?>
```

That should do it.

Answer (score 0):

I had this a long while ago, I used a method similar to this:

http://webdesign.about.com/od/php/ht/force_download.htm